# Which javascript Automated Testing Tool to use

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, npm

I am looking for an npm/javascript based Automated Testing tool with which I can test my website providing scripted input values and then for example clicking submit button on page etc.
So far I have tested [Dalekjs](http://dalekjs.com/index.html) but it seems to have lots of problems especially with Firefox, plus some CSS selectors are also not working even in other Browsers.

Is there any other good Automation testing tool that is npm based but does not necessarily require Selenium?

Answer (score 6):

## Nightmare.js

There's a really awesome tool called [Nightmare.js](http://www.nightmarejs.org/). First it was a hight-level Phantom wrapper, but since v2 it was rewritten on Atom. Nightmare is webkit-based.

Nightmare can be executed headlessly, but you'll probably need to configure your server to get that working.

Why Nightmare? Here's a code sample from the official site:

#### Nightmare.js

```
yield Nightmare()
  .goto('http://yahoo.com')
  .type('input[title="Search"]', 'github nightmare')
  .click('.searchsubmit');
```

Comparing to:

#### Phantom.js

```
phantom.create(function (ph) {
  ph.createPage(function (page) {
    page.open('http://yahoo.com', function (status) {
      page.evaluate(function () {
        var el =
          document.querySelector('input[title="Search"]');
        el.value = 'github nightmare';
      }, function (result) {
        page.evaluate(function () {
          var el = document.querySelector('.searchsubmit');
          var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');
          event.initEvent('click', true, false);
          el.dispatchEvent(event);
        }, function (result) {
          ph.exit();
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

So you'll have to write significantly less code.

## BUT IT'S WEBKIT-ONLY

---

## Selenium

In order to get something working in all browsers, take a look at [Selenium](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver). It [supports really many browsers and platforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium).

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = require('selenium-webdriver').By,
    until = require('selenium-webdriver').until;

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('firefox')
    .build();

driver.get('http://www.google.com/ncr');
driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver');
driver.findElement(By.name('btnG')).click();
driver.wait(until.titleIs('webdriver - Google Search'), 1000);
driver.quit();
```

*Just a small advice* Selenium tests are likely to be more "bulky" than nightmare tests and I've seen quite a lot "Promise hell" in Selenium tests on one of my previous jobs, so before you start, my advice to you would be to use of generators and [`co`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/co) or some other control flow library.

Comment: My concern is, does it work across all Browsers and also just using npm/js?

Comment: @FaisalMq no, it isn't. Added another tool to the answer.

Comment: Nightmare.js is no longer properly maintained. It has disclosed and unfixed zero-day holes: https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/1060

Answer (score 2):

### try http://phantomjs.org/

It might be an excellent alternative to Dalekjs. Phantom.js is runnable without a UI, scriptable via JavaScript and is used for automating web page interaction. It's a WebKit with its own JavaScript API. It has fast and native support for most web standards: DOM handling, CSS selector, JSON, Canvas, and SVG. You can use scripted input values

Here is a sample usage:

```
console.log('Loading a web page');
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/';
page.open(url, function (status) {
  console.log('Page loaded');
  page.render('wikipedia.org.png');
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had a similar requirement, I did below investigation which would be helpful:[image]

Comment: That can be very helpful to people! I think you should add nightmare.js to the list and publish it

Answer (score 0):

NightmareJS is actually based on PhantomJS. It works very well even for a non-dev. In reality automated testing truly depends on many situations and the type of application tested. You need a super fast way to visually see if changes to the code is affecting the app visually and also to some degree its logic. For logic there are many other frameworks for that like selenium frameworks. No need for complex coding as you want to be able to view the application or test results quick, modify the variable or elements that neeeds to be tested and verified.

Comment: To work with multiple browsers download the appropriate drivers for Selenium to get them working and have them reference the drivers in Eclipse or Visual studio